# Generate every binary n x m matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, binary

I'd like to generate every boolean matrix in matlab as a 3-dimensional array.

For example:

```
mat(:,:,1) = [[1 0][0 1]]
mat(:,:,2) = [[1 1][0 1]]
...
```

My final goal is to generate every trinary matrix of a given size.
Keep in mind that I know that the number of matrices is exponential, but I'll use small numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that the previous answer actually does what you want... With that method, I get multiple entries in array2D that are the same. Here is a vectorised and (I believe) correct solution:

```
clear all;

nRows = 2;
nCols = nRows; % Only works for square matrices

% Generate matrix of all binary numbers that fit in nCols
max2Pow = nCols;
maxNum = 2 ^ max2Pow - 1; 
allBinCols = bsxfun(@bitand, (0:maxNum)', 2.^((max2Pow-1):-1:0)) > 0;

% Get the indices of the rows in this matrix required for each output
% binary matrix
N = size(allBinCols, 1);
A = repmat({1:N}, nCols, 1);
[B{1:nCols}] = ndgrid(A{:});
rowInds = reshape(cat(3, B{:}), [], nCols)';

% Get the appropriate rows and reshape to a 3D array of right size
nMats = size(rowInds, 2);
binMats = reshape(allBinCols(rowInds(:), :)', nRows, nCols, nMats)
```

Note that for anything other than small numbers of `nRows` you will run out of memory pretty quickly, because you're generating `2^(nRows*nRows)` matrices of size `nRows*nRows`. ThatsAlottaNumbers.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer is pretty straightforward. Each matrix being boolean, it can be indexed by the binary number obtained when reading all the values in any given order.

For a binary matrix: let n be the number of element in your matrix (n = rows * cols).

```
for d=0:(2^n-1)
    %Convert binary to decimal string
    str = dec2bin(d);
    %Convert string to array
    array1D = str - '0';
    array1D = [array1D zeros(1, n-length(array1D))];
    %Reshape
    array2D(:,:,d+1) = reshape(array1D, rows, cols);
end
```

This can be very easily generalized to any base by changing dec2bin into dec2base and changing 2^n into (yourbase)^n.